# Delphi code will not save to Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, lazarus

Ok i come from a C# background. This did not save to the Mysql database Table. I struggled to have it communicate with the database, but its not inserting to the database Table. it just shows the messagebox, but when i refresh, nothing shows up in the database. Code looks like this

```
unit mysqlConn;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, sqldb, mysql56conn, Forms, Controls, Graphics,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    MySQL56Connection1: TMySQL56Connection;
    SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery;
    SQLTransaction1: TSQLTransaction;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('insert into people_info(name,email,telephone,gender)');
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('values(:name,:email,:telephone,:gender)');
  SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('name').AsString:=Edit1.Text;
  SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('email').AsString:=Edit2.Text;
  SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('telephone').AsString:=Edit3.Text;
  SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('gender').AsString:=Edit4.Text;
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL;
  showmessage('Ok I am saved!');
end;

end.
```

What Do i appear to be missing ?

Comment: The TSqlQuery, TMySQL56Connection and TSQLTransaction are Lazarus components, not Delphi ones, so referring to Delphi in your q title and tags is misleading.  Also, you should add the contents of your form's .LFM file to your q, otherwise readers cannot know whether the DB components are correctly configured.

Comment: I got it solved. I do remember adding a Lazarus Tag,. But thanks again

Comment: I see nothing in your above code that would result in not saving. My guess would be that the problem was somewhere else, outside of the code you showed us.

Comment: @JerryDodge, Please see answer

Comment: Please [edit] your question title. Delphi does not use `{$mode objfpc}` or `.lfm` files, so this is not Delphi code.

Answer (score 2):

I did not add the SQLTransaction1.Commit and hence Saving to the Database was null and Void.
Code looks like this now :

```
unit mysqlConn;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, sqldb, mysql56conn, Forms, Controls, Graphics,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    MySQL56Connection1: TMySQL56Connection;
    SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery;
    SQLTransaction1: TSQLTransaction;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  SqlQuery1.SQL.text:='insert into people_info (name, email, telephone, gender) values (:name,:email,:telephone,:gender)';
  SqlQuery1.Params.ParamByName('name').AsString := Edit1.text;
  SqlQuery1.Params.ParamByName('email').AsString := Edit2.text;
  SqlQuery1.Params.ParamByName('telephone').AsString := Edit3.text;
  SqlQuery1.Params.ParamByName('gender').AsString := Edit4.text;
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL;
  SQLTransaction1.Commit; // This saved to the database
  showmessage('Ok I am saved!');
  Edit1.Text := '';
  Edit2.Text := '';
  Edit3.Text := '';
  Edit4.Text := '';
end;

end.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with these components on Lazarus, but on Delphi, you only need to `Commit` if you previously used `BeginTran`.